# Only save icon not appear in material table

Tags: typescript, material-table

I have only save icon not appear error in editable table.Outside action icon is work but inner action is not work.

#### click update action

[image]

#### click add action

[image]

#### click delete action

[image]

#### Action icon and also new action is work

[image]

```
<MaterialTable  title="Selling" columns={columns} data={data} icons={tableIcons}
```

tableicons

```
const tableIcons = {
     Save: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <Save {...props} ref={ref} />),
     Add: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
     Edit: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
     Delete: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <Delete {...props} ref={ref} />),
     Cancel: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <Cancel {...props} ref={ref} />),
     Clear: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
Check: forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
```

Add check icon